# A problem in the spirit of P. Borwein's polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials

A well-known conjecture (now a theorem) of P. Borwein (see [Wang and Krattenthaler - An asymptotic approach to Borwein-type sign pattern theorems](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.12415)) states:
*For all positive integers $n$, the sign pattern of the
coefficients in the expansion of the polynomial
$$P_n(q) := (1 −q)(1 −q^2)(1 −q^4)(1 −q^5) ···(1 −q^{3n−2})(1 −q^{3n−1})$$
is ${+}{-}{-}{+}{-}{-}\cdots$, with a coefficient $0$ being considered as both $+$ and $−$.*

I'm considering a variant of this problem. Define the polynomial
$$Q_n(q):=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(1-q^{3k-2})(1-q^{3k-1})}{1-q}.$$
Based on some experiments, I would like to ask:

> **CLAIM.** The coefficients of $Q_n(q)$ make **exactly** $n$ change of signs, running in blocks of **almost** equal sizes.
>
> **Convention:** a coefficient $0$ is treated as both $+$ and $-$.
>
> **QUESTION:** Is the claim true?

Comment: Do you have an off-by-one error? I get $Q_2(q)=(1+q)(1-q^4)(1-q^5)$ $=q^{10}+q^9-q^6-2q^5-q^4+q+1$ with two sign changes, not the three that you suggest. Or do you mean $n+1$ same-sign blocks? In either case, the lower-bound side of your statement at least is easy from Descartes...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Of yeah, it should be $n$ not $n+1$.

Comment: Quite interesting problem. Numerical results suggests the peak of $|Q_n(q)|$ on the unit circle occurs at about $\pm \pi/(3n+O(1))$, which is consistent with a sign pattern of period $6n+O(1)$ and thus $n+O(1)$ blocks of roughly the same size. The claim is probably true.